# Retrieving a collection of user emails for Notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to schedule a task that will send an email notification to selected users that have placed reservation for a particular product when a certain condition is met. Here's how the task is setup

```
$schedule->call(function () {

    // get reservation collection
    $reservations = Reservation::all();

    // iterate over reservation collection
    foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {

        // get difference in hours between now and product start date
        $timeDiff = Carbon::parse($reservation->product->start)->diffInHours();

        // send mail notification to reservation owners
        if ($timeDiff > 2) {

            // get users who reserved the product
            $users = Reservation::where('product_id', $reservation->product_id)->pluck($reservation->user->username);

            //notify user
            Notification::send($users, new ReservedProductPurchase($reservation));
        }
    }
})->everyMinute();
```

When I run the command `php artisan schedule:run`, it throws an error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mymail@domain.com' in
>     'field list' (SQL: select `mymail@domain`.`com` from `reservations` where `product_id` = 2)

Of course I am not saving emails(username in this case) in my reservations table which is why the error occurs.

The relationship between a user and a reservation is `One To Many` which means a user `hasMany` reservations and a reservation `belongsTo` a user.

How should I go about retrieve a collection of the emails(usernames) that I want the notification sent to?

Comment: can you show us the content of your select Reservation::all() because i see you are trying to select the content of column and not the column "select mymail@domain.com from reservations where product_id = 2" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notification::send()` wants a collection of *notifiable entities* not a collection of emails, so first you have to add the correct *trait* to the `User` model:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Then you can retreive the users that has a certain reservation:

```
// get users who reserved the product
$users = User::whereHas('reservations', function (Builder $query) use ($reservation)
{
    $query->where('product_id', $reservation->product_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: This line `Notification::send() wants a collection of notifiable entities not a collection of emails` made me realize I was actually doing it wrong. Thanks for the clear explanation and the solution. It did the magic.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage is a bit wrong, the `pluck` method accepts the `column` name and what you pass is the value, which is the user email. So that's why it says that a column with that email address could not be found. You can try this instead:

```
Reservation::with('user')
    ->where('product_id', $reservation->product_id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('user.email')
    ->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what column stores your username field. But assuming the column name is `username`. You should pluck that column, not the `email`. Like this:

```
$users = Reservation::where('product_id', $reservation->product_id)->pluck('username');
```

Basically: pass column name in `pluck()` method